# What makes these two Python codes with different indentation produces different result

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

**Edit.**: I APOLOGIZE FOR MY QUESTION, I was sleepy and working in an IDE with different default indentation level that I'm not familiar with. It didn't occur to me at all that the indentation was off, even after I pasted and redo my code in Jupyter. I'll pay more attention to the tab-space setting next time when playing with a new python tool.

From what I have always believed prior to this case, I always thought that Python code works the same no matter if the indentation is made with space or tab, as long as their levels are relative to the parent, until I stumbled upon this scenario where these two codes produce a different output. The first one was made from my usual everyday IDE, Jupyter Notebook, while the second one was produced from Google DataLab notebook which was actually my first time using it. Surprisingly, unlike Jupyter, it didn't give me any indentation warning (by turning red) at all. I later found the cause of this bug after I pasted it on Jupyter, which several lines became red.

Code #1

```
import numpy as np

A = [1,53,24,65,76,34]

for j in range(len(A)-1):
    min_index = j
    for i in range(j+1, len(A)):
        if (A[i] < A[min_index]):
            min_index = i

    if(min_index != j):
        A[min_index],  A[j] = A[j], A[min_index]


print A
```

Code #2

```
import numpy as np

A = [1,53,24,65,76,34]

for j in range(len(A)-1):
  min_index = j
  for i in range(j+1, len(A)):
    if (A[i] < A[min_index]):
      min_index = i

    if(min_index != j):
      A[min_index],  A[j] = A[j], A[min_index]

print A
```

Comment: In the second block, the second `if` statement is indented by one additional level. Are you familiar with Python's reliance on indentation?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks for pointing out !! I wondered how did I missed that, I guess I didn't get used to 2-space indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, the second `if` is outside the inner `for` loop, but in the second example, it's *within* the loop. Since it's only being iterated over once per outer loop in the second block, the result is obviously going to be different.